Convex absorbing set
Let $X$ be a normed vector space. I'm aware a convex absorbing set $A\subset X$ might have empty interior. However, I wonder whether the following is true?

Let $X$ be a normed space and $A\subset X$ a convex absorbing set. Then, every sequence $(x_n)$ s.t. $x_n\to 0$ and that their normalized sequence $\left(x_n / \|x_n\|\right)$ is Cauchy eventually lies in $A$.

If $X$ is Banach, then $x_n / \|x_n\|\to u$ where $u\in X$ is some unit vector. Since $A$ is absorbing, there exists some $r_u>0$ s.t. $t u\in A$ for all $t\in[0, r_u)$. Choose $t_0\in (0,r_u)$ and let $u':=t_0u\in A$.
Then I want to show for some large $N$, if $n>N$, then $u'+r_n(x_n-u')\in A$ for some $r_n>1$. Then use convexity to conclude $x_n\in A$. But I'm stuck.
If this is true for Banach space, then for normed space we can always go to its completion. I can't seem to find a counterexample either. Thanks in advance.
Update. It seems the above is equivalent to the following

Let $X$ be a normed space and $A\subset X$ convex absorbing. If $u$ is a unit vector then there exists $\epsilon>0$ s.t. $\inf\{p(x):\|x-u\|<\epsilon\}>0$, where $p$ is the Minkowski functional.

